# Page not found (404 )

Tags: python, django

Error is :

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/'
Using the URLconf defined in orangeowl.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
    ^product/$
    ^product/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$
The current URL, admin/, didn't match any of these.
```

*urls.py*

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import admin
from website.models import Product
from website.views import index

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', admin.site.urls), #Lets us access the admin page
    (r'^$', 'orangeowl.website.views.index'),
)


urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.list_detail',
    url(r'^product/$', 'object_list',
        {'queryset': Product.objects.all()}),
    url(r'^product/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'object_detail',
        {'queryset': Product.objects.all()})
)
```

*views.py*

```
from models import Catalog
from models import Product
from models import CatalogCategory
from models import ProductAttribute
from models import ProductDetail
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def index(request): #Define our function, accept a request

    catalog = Catalog.objects.all()
    catalogcategory = CatalogCategory.objects.all()
    product = Product.objects.all()
    productattribute = ProductAttribute.objects.all()
    productdetail = ProductDetail.objects.all()




    return render_to_response('index.html', {'catalog': catalog}, {'product':product})
    return render_to_response('product_detail.html', {'productdetail': productdetail})
    return render_to_response('product_list.html', {'productattribute': productattribute})
```

*settings.py*

```
ROOT_URL_CONF = project.urls

INSTALLED_APPS = project.appname
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Access admin page?

Comment: Yeah, access the admin page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice that you are defining `urlpatterns` twice. That's why `admin`'s is not included. You can do like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', (r'^admin/', admin.site.urls), #Lets us access the admin page
(r'^$', 'orangeowl.website.views.index'),
)
urlpatterns += patterns('django.views.generic.list_detail',
url(r'^product/$', 'object_list',
{'queryset': Product.objects.all()}),
url(r'^product/(?P[-\w]+)/$', 'object_detail',
{'queryset': Product.objects.all()})
)
```

Hope this helps!